# add a footer to gridview in android

Tags: android

I want to ask a question that, Is there any method to design a textview or any control at the footer or bottom of the grid view. Because gridview doesn't have any footer related property and we can not add a scrollview on gridview thats why how can we implement this as show a textview in the bottom of the grid view or in the footer of the gridview. Please help me out about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking. You want to display textview down bottom of screen like a footer? could add this attribute to textview

```
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```